# Firefox reacting to JQuery setTimeout that doesn't apply

Tags: jquery, firefox, settimeout

http://cfk18.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ <- Only pay attention to the first image.

I seem to be having a problem where some jquery in firefox isn't working...but IE is (I know, I know)

```
var hover = $('#par1'),
    box = $('.sq1');
hover.hover(function () { 
    box.toggleClass('index2');
});
```

And

```
var linkloc = $('#par1'),
    link = $('#frnt1');
linkloc.on('mouseenter', function() {
    function linkadd() {  
        link.html("<a target=_blank href=http://www.google.co.uk><img src=small1.JPG /></a>"); } 
    setTimeout(linkadd, 1500)    
});

linkloc.on('mouseleave',function(){
    link.html("<img src=small1.JPG />");
});
```

I appreciate the code may be a bit messy, but I am still learning as I go.

Now the problem is, the top piece of code is reacting to the setTimeout in the bottom. (It repeatedly toggles in time with the setTimeout) Even though it calls the function name in it. This doesn't happen in IE though.

If I remove the setTimeout, the top piece of code works fine, but I do need it for the bottom piece.

I would include more code (and can if necessary) but it will get very messy and won't load well on jsfiddle due to the missing images.

I also have the issue that on moving my mouse away, the bottom piece correctly removes the href from the html...but then after the timeout period adds it back. This also doesn't happen in IE.

Comment: First of all, close add the quotes for src here: src='small1.JPG'. The same for hfref

Comment: What do you mean by "reacting the setTimeout"?

Comment: The toggleclass command is firing off repeatedly to the setTimeout time.  But it only fires once (as I want) if I remove it.

Comment: So, does the quotes fix your problem? Or do you have some other issues?

Comment: The quotes did not fix the issue I'm afraid. Sorry should have pointed out I had remedied that.

Comment: @Umbr44 Change your mouseenter event to `setTimeout(function(){ link.html("<a target='_blank' href='http://www.google.co.uk'><img src='small1.JPG' /></a>"); }, 1500)`

Comment: I tried this...it sort of works...I'm not sure why but if I refresh the screen multiple time I am now finding that sometimes this fixes the issue, and sometimes it is still there.

Comment: http://cfk18.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/  <- Only pay attention to the first image, the jquery/css for all others has not been touched yet.

Comment: Every time you enter the DIV, you set another timer. But you never cancel the old timer. So if you enter the DIV multiple times, you'll run the timer multiple times.

Comment: Yes but the toggleclass shouldn't be affected by the timeout anyway should it? And I am talking about purely leaving my mouse over the hover area, this is making the toggleclass go off repeatedly. So that wouldn't be entering the DIV multiple times would it?

Comment: What I see is that when I leave the div, sometimes it toggles the class twice. I'm not sure what this has to do with the `setTimeout`. Can you make a jsfiddle that just contains the relevant code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PLE3B/    Although looking at it, that doesn't seem to be working now. Most likely as the image is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the timer when you leave the DIV:

```
var linkloc = $('#par1'),
    link = $('#frnt1'),
    timer = null;
linkloc.on('mouseenter', function() {
    function linkadd() {  
        link.html("<a target=_blank href=http://www.google.co.uk><img src=small1.JPG /></a>"); } 
    timer = setTimeout(linkadd, 1500)    
});

linkloc.on('mouseleave',function(){
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
    link.html("<img src=small1.JPG />");
});
```

Comment: If you want to shorten this a tiny bit, `clearTimeout` works even if `timer` is `null`. This code is probably clearer, though.

Comment: I am still getting the issue (Almost 80% on first load and 50/50 on refreshes on the page)  Surely if it's a coding issue it should happen every time :S                                             http://cfk18.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ <- I have updated this with your Jquery and still get the issue.